# Trying to simplify Nash's proof for the 2 player case (Symmetric game)

Tags: game-theory, symmetry

> Show that in any 2 player symmetric game there is always a symmetric
>   Nash equilibrium where both players play the same strategy

I read the proof for n-player game [in page 12 here](http://rbsc.princeton.edu/sites/default/files/Non-Cooperative_Games_Nash.pdf) and all the permutations made it really hard for me to read and understand..Does anyone have a proof or can help me simplify it for n=2?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a non-degenerate game there is an indirect way through an argument provided by the Lemke Howson algorithm, namely that any non-degenerate bimatrix game (here I added finite to your assumptions, otherwise this seemingly obvious statement is not true: there are infinte/discontinuous symmetric games with only asymmetric Nash equilibria) has an odd number of equilibria. Hence, knowing that

1. there is an odd number of equilibria in any non-degenerate bimatrix game,
2. for $x\neq y$, where $x,y$ are strategies, it is immediate to show that if $(x,y)$ is an equilibrium of a symmetric bimatrix game, then $(y,x)$ is an equilibrium as well

you can conclude that there is an even number of equilibria of the form $(x,y)$ with $x\neq y$ which imiplies that there must a $x^S$ such that $(x^S,x^S)$ is an equilibrium.

---

Proof of point 2. Let $\alpha(x,y)$ denote the payoff function of player I, where $(x,y)\in X\times X$, where $X$ is the common strategy space. Let $\beta(x,y)$ denote the payoff function of player II. By symmetry 
$$\beta(x,y)=\alpha(y,x)\tag{sym}$$ Now, assume that $(x',y')$ is a Nash equilibrium of this bimatrix game, then $$\alpha(x',y')\ge\alpha(x,y'), \quad \forall x\in X\tag1$$ and $$\beta(x',y')\ge \beta(x',y), \quad \forall y \in X\tag2$$ Rewrite the conditions in view of the symmetric property $(\text{sym})$to obtain that $$\alpha(y',x')\ge \alpha(y,x'),\quad \forall y\in X\tag{2'}$$ and $$\beta(y',x')\ge \beta(y',x),\quad \forall x\in X\tag{1'}$$ Now, $(1')$ and $(2')$ together imply that $(y',x')$ is a Nash equilibrium of the simultaneous move game.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, point 2 you made is clear to me, however I don't know the Lemke-Howson Algorithm, I will read more about it to try and figure out why the 1st point is true, unless there is some alternative way to prove point one, do you (or anyone) know one?

Comment: It is also called (not cold, haha) Wilson's Oddity Theorem, but to my knowledge there is no trivial/immediate proof

Comment: @lfc What's your math (in particular,  topology) background? Kohlberg & Mertens (1985) proved something about what the manifold of all (for fixed set of agents/actions per agent) Nash equilibria of all games looks like (a deformed rubber sphere floating above a 'sphere' of games).  Oddity at 'nice' points (not on a 'cusp' or doubling-back point of this manifold) follows from a Brouwer degree argument.  If you'd like I can elaborate more!

Comment: My topology background is analysis and set theory, I don't know if I'll understand it, but if you can elaborate I'll at least try to.